# Image of closed unit ball and its closure contained in $\prod_{y \in \ell^\infty}[-\|y\|_\infty,\|y\|_\infty]$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, functional-analysis, inner-products

> Consider the map $\phi : \ell^1 \to \prod_{y \in \ell^\infty} \mathbb R_y$, $x \mapsto (\langle y,x\rangle_{\ell^\infty,\ell^1})_{y \in \ell^\infty}$, where $\langle y,x\rangle_{\ell^\infty,\ell^1}= \sum_{n \ge 1} y_n x_n$ and denote by $K_1(0,\ell^1)$ the closed unit ball in $\ell^1$.

I'm trying to show that $\phi(K_1(0,\ell^1)) \subset \prod_{y \in \ell^\infty}[-\|y\|_\infty,\|y\|_\infty]$ and that the closure of $\phi(K_1(0,\ell^1))$ is contained in $\prod_{y \in \ell^\infty}[-\|y\|_\infty,\|y\|_\infty]$ with respect to the product topology.

But I'm kind of lost and I'm not sure where to start to show these statements. I would be glad if someone could help me and give me some hint.

Comment: To see that the image of the ball is contained in those intervals: If $\pi_y$ is the projection onto the $y$ component, then $\pi_y(\phi(x))=\langle y,x\rangle$ which has modulus smaller than $\|y\|_\infty \|x\|_1$.

Comment: Thanks @s.harp ! Will try to solve it with your hint.